# How to read files with headers in Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill, qliksense

When I setup Apache Drill like so:

```
"csv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "csv2"
  ],
  "skipFirstLine": false,
  "extractHeader": true,
  "delimiter": ","
},
```

The SkipFirstLine disappears when I save the configuration file - Why?

Comment: whoops - edit: changed go to drill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default value of these boolean properties `skipFirstLine`, `extractHeader` is false. It will only be seen in the plugin json if it's true.

Make `"extractHeader": false` and update plugin configuration, this will also disappear.